# Download images from Google Drive using the REST api

Tags: javascript, rest, google-drive-api, fetch-api

I'm trying to download users images in the browser using the google drive rest api, but I can't seem to get to the actual image data. I'm able to successfully call the files endpoint, but I don't know what to do with the response.

my fetch request:

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?key=${driveInfo.key}`, settings)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log("drive json", json);
    });
```

which outputs:

```
drive json
{
kind: "drive#file"
id: "1qXXBU6oIxs2Y4PZskA-kj6ljMjTfGKjf"
name: "Screenshot_20180919-160538.png"
mimeType: "image/png"
}
```

I've also noticed that `response.body` is a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` which is great, as I ultimately need a uint8 array, but it looks like the uint8 array represents the above meta data rather than the actual image data.

Am I even going about this the right way, or am I way off in this attempt to download images in the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to download the file from Google Drive with the API key using `fetch` of Javascript.
- The file is publicly shared.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to download the file as the binary data, please add `alt=media` to the query parameter.

  - When `alt=media` is not used, the file metadata is returned.

#### Modified script:

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?key=${driveInfo.key}&alt=media`, settings)
  .then(res => {
    return res.arrayBuffer();
  })
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data);
  });
```

#### Note:

- When the file is not publicly shared, the file cannot be downloaded by the API key. Please be careful this.
- In above script, the data is retrieved as arrayBuffer.

  - If you want to retrieve the data as the blob, please modify `return res.arrayBuffer();` to `return res.blob();`

#### References:

- [Download a file stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)
- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: The alt=media parameter did the trick, many thanks! I'll also note that the images I'm testing on are in fact not public, but I pass an authorization token as part of the fetch settings object in my code. This seems to work fine

Comment: @Jesse Sliter Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.