# insert data from a text file into a google site

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, fetch-api, google-sites-2016

I am trying to insert text from a `*.txt` file into a google site.

this is what i have tried so far (using `fetch`), but my search is exhausted:

```
<html>

<body>
<div id="text-container"></div>

<script>
  fetch("G:/My Drive/path/to/test_file/test.txt")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      document.getElementById('text-container').innerHTML = text;
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

But all I get is a blank.

I know the text file exists because i **can embed the whole file** (from the same location), but i just want to extract the relevant text into the google site and **not** the whole file (which is an undesired alternative).

I see that other answers that require GOOGLE API (from 2017) are potentially available here as a workaround, but do not appear to work now (in 2023): [JavaScript read all text from txt file on Google drive or Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447071/javascript-read-all-text-from-txt-file-on-google-drive-or-dropbox)

But this would be rather cumbersome for extracting small pieces of text.

How can this be achieved?

---

Note: The text file lives in Google Drive. I can embed the entire file (which looks rather ugly, link to a file), so I want to take just the text content into the html... both the Google Site and the text document are in the same folder.

Comment: Possibly a CORS policy issue? Why not upload the file to Google Drive, and load/embed from there?

Comment: @PeterThoeny.  the text file already lives in google drive.  i can embed the entire file (which looks rather ugly, link to a file), so i want to take just the text content into the html...  both the google side and the text document are in the same folder.

Comment: This here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71409801/7475450

Comment: @PeterThoeny: so basically, according to the link posted, this needs to be done via an API ?

Comment: That answer is Google apps script specific. If you use that you likely want to text from the blob, e.g. `let html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {...})).getBlob().getDataAsString();`. However, it looks like you run that code in the browser, so you could use a fetch using the Google drive URL of a file, but need to provide the proper authorization header with token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript read all text from txt file on Google drive or Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447071/javascript-read-all-text-from-txt-file-on-google-drive-or-dropbox)

Comment: @Rubén, that was from the same link that i tried to implement this into the google site (via `embed code`), but was unable to.  I create a simple text file with "hello world" and for example want to get "hello" into the google site page.  (ie. a very basic requirement).

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` can't access a file stored in a local unit. It should use an URL (not local file path) or a request.

To access files stored in Google Drive you might have to use the Google Drive API or Google Apps Script (i.e. create a web app and use the Drive Service).

---

A link taken from the Google Drive user interface to the file will not work to directly get the text from a txt file. If you don't want to use the Google Drive API / Google Apps Script you could use hand crafted URL... -> [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15557392/1595451). While this question title mentions image, the hand crafting method works for other types for files. Note this is a hacky solution, it might be great for hobby / small projects but I don't think that it should be used in large projects.

---

**Reference**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

---

**Related**

<sup>Grouped by tag used to in the search query</sup>

[google-drive-api](/questions/tagged/google-drive-api)

- [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15557392/1595451)
- [JavaScript read all text from txt file on Google drive or Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38447071/1595451)
- [Retrieving a raw file URL from the Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67813895/1595451)

[fetch-api](/questions/tagged/fetch-api)[google-drive-api](/questions/tagged/google-drive-api)

- [Download images from Google Drive using the REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59761645/1595451)
- [how to open folder of google drive using google drive api in axios/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71253848/1595451)
- [How can I fetch a public image from google drive using the File ID (not using node)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71388663/1595451)

Comment: so if there is a public URL as in a google share link, would `fetch` then work ?

Comment: I think that using a link to the file will not work to directly get the text from a txt file. If you don't want to use the Google Drive API / Google Apps Script you could use hand crafted URL... -> [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15557392/1595451)

Comment: images are actually fine. Once can create images and store them and google sites permits the upload of images (so when they are modified the image updates). The same is **so far not true for text** and this is what the question seeks to resolve.

Comment: See my last edit to the answer and the suggested original.